# Tkinter Button Image Quality Bad

Tags: python, tkinter, button, image-quality

I'm making a tkinter app and the image I've assigned to the button appears low quality, even though the image is actually crisp and isn't in as bad quality. Is there any way to fix this? The red and blue buttons are in bad quality

[image]

Comment: If your on windows, try to go to display properties and disable 'Let windows fix blurry apps', IIRC. And also set a custom scaling factor(maybe125). And try again. Blurry GUI is a common problem due to windows scaling bug. You can also google for other fixes

Answer (score 0):

The image is kind of blurry and this can happen through resizing the image. By resizing you alter the information of the image and some information get lost by resizing it.

You could try another image that actually has the size you wish, better create an image via PIL with the desired properties. Or why bother and use just a monospaced font that fits and use the background and the foreground option to get the disred output.

Comment: However, I think the real issue here is windows GUI blurry because of automatic scaling by windows.

Comment: @CoolCloud I think in the end is resizing and scaling the same. Your approach however is different and can lead to the desired output. While we dont have the information needed to varify an sadisfying result, you could write this as an answer.

Comment: Yep we do not have enough information, but my conclusion was because 'Date' text was also blurry, which could means it is a windows text related issue. Have had this myself every time after a fresh install of windows.

Comment: @CoolCloud Good point, didnt notice that.